# C# How to extend class that exist in a different dll by adding a property to it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have n-tier application that has many layers in different assemblies.
i use entity framework 6.1 and i want to add `ObjectState` property to the base entity to track entity states. The problem is `BaseEntity` is located in my domain objects dll that is database independent and i want to add `ObjectState` in the Entity Framework project as this property is entity framework related.How to achieve this behavior?

```
public enum ObjectState
{
    Unchanged,
    Added,
    Modified,
    Deleted
}
public interface IObjectState
{
    [NotMapped]
    ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If the class is public and not sealed, what's the problem with inheritance? I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: Is the problem the `NotMapped` attribute? Could you use EF's fluent configuration to ensure that property is not mapped instead?

Comment: Hello, I don't want to add the property ObjectState into my Base Entity as this is the base of my domain and this property is Entity Framework specific

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx), if you can edit the code of your domain objects projects and declare the base entity as partial class.

```
namespace DomainNameSpace 
{
    public partial class BaseEntity
    {
        // Your properties and method
    }
}
```

Then in your Entity Framework project you can add the following code:

```
namespace DomainNameSpace 
{
    public partial class BaseEntity
    {
        public enum ObjectState
        {
            Unchanged,
            Added,
            Modified,
            Deleted
        }
        public interface IObjectState
        {
            [NotMapped]
            ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you can't edit the files in domain project or don't like this approach,   maybe inheritance can help. In your Entity Framework project create a class like the following.

```
namespace YourProjectNameSpace 
{
    public class StatefulEntityClassName : BaseEntity
    {
        public enum ObjectState
        {
            Unchanged,
            Added,
            Modified,
            Deleted
        }
        public interface IObjectState
        {
            [NotMapped]
            ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks but the partial classes must be in the same project(dll)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, that you can't implement `IObjectState` in `BaseEntity`, because it must be independent from EF specific, then you should have two sets of entities - one for domain, one for EF, and use mapping (possibly, [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)) between these sets:

```
// domain entities assembly
public abstract class BaseEntity { }

// EF entities assembly
public abstract class BaseEFEntity : IObjectState

// somewhere in the code
Mapper.Map(domainEntity, efEntity);
```

Actually, when using layered architecture, this is a preferable way, when each layer operates its specific models.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this will add another layer as i already has Dto layer and so, will add complexity to the application